# Sending canvas data to server

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a canvas in my web page. Here the user draws an image. Now when the user clicks the submit button I want the browser to send the canvas data along with other fields.
 Is it possible to send the canvas data. If yes how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

will return your image data as a data: URI
You can set it to a hidden field and submit it with your form.
Or you can send it via AJAX request.

You can create another an image with the URI, and redraw the image

```
var imageURI = ...
// TODO: get the URI
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() {
  ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
}
img.src = imageURI;
```

Comment: How is the image encoded. I am asking this because I will send this image to another client's browser and I want to display that image back into the canvas.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer was quite useful:)